# How to define a variable for the rows of data that are moved

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

This function works standalone to move a row of data over to a different sheet. I'm grasping that I need to capture that row of data into a variable so I can handle it in another function. But I have considered and tried various ideas for capturing the row using the variables defined there already but weeks are going by with no progress.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  var row = r.getRow();
  var column = r.getColumn();
  //moving from the Form Responses 1 sheet to the Processed sheet
  if(s.getName() == "Form Responses 1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  var ProOrd = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(target);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ProOrd, 'Details have been archived to the Processed sheet')
}
```

Can someone show how to get that row into a variable for massaging beyond just moving it to the other sheet?

---

I want to take that "target" data and push it out to a dialog box. The end user will put the info into another software and dismiss this dialog. It requires no interaction other than for them to dismiss the window. When I run this function on my sheet now, the debugger runs clean but stacklogger says

> "You do not have permission to call showModelessDialog at onEdit(TestCode:16)"

---

I resolved that and renamed the function since it could conflict with the event trigger I had to set.  So this is the code I have now:

```
function onConf(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  var row = r.getRow();
  var column = r.getColumn();
  //moving from the Form Responses 1 sheet to the Processed sheet
  if(s.getName() == "Form Responses 1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  var ProOrd = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(numColumns);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ProOrd, 'Details have been archived to the Processed sheet')
}
```

As it was suggested that I have this data captured already (and it makes sense to me. I don't see how it moves the data without capturing it).
But here I've tried:

```
var ProOrd = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(target);
var ProOrd = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(numColumns);
var ProOrd = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(row);
```

Using target the message only says "undefined".
Using numColumns the message says "7".
Using row  the message says "2".
Even I can't see it making sense to use the  "s"  or  "r"  variables.
So I tried this:

```
  if(s.getName() == "Form Responses 1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    var outPUT = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  var ProOrd = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(outPUT);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ProOrd, 'Details have been archived to the Processed sheet')
}
```

but defining the `outPUT` variable that way also results in an "Undefined" message in the dialog.  Drat.  Where is that row of info hiding?

I've managed a bit more success!
I have this code now:

```
function onConf(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  var row = r.getRow();
  var column = r.getColumn();
     //moving from the Form Responses 1 sheet to the Processed sheet
  if(s.getName() == "Form Responses 1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); // added
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  var ProOrd = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(**data**);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ProOrd, 'Details have been archived to the Processed sheet')
}
```

I've been reading and tried BOLDing the new code line for the variable `data` and it's call in the html code.  But it seems to have just added two asterisks before and after, I don't see it bolded in the dialog.

I DO get an array of data now in the pushed dialog!
However it's ALL of the lines in the sheet vs. just the one line that fits the `true` condition.  Including "False" reports on all the open lines in the sheet.

How can I limit this array to only contain the data that fits the condition?
It SHOULD be only one rows worth of data at a time actually.  I've attached an image.  There were 3 lines of info in the sheet at the time.  I clicked on the 3rd row PROCESS NEXT and it moved that row of data and pushed the array to the dialog.  You can see that 3rd row of data (for my Pierce Arrow) in the presentation and can note in the background that it has moved. It's on the other sheet now just as wanted.

[image]

I thought placing the data variable in the code where I did, would capture the array of data AFTER the true condition had been recognized.
Obviously not good at this, but I'm learning and I'm persistent.

Have been working on this virtually all weekend and made some progress but don't yet understand.  This is the code I have right at the moment:

```
function onConf(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  var row = r.getRow();
  var column = r.getColumn();
     //moving from the Form Responses 1 sheet to the Processed sheet
  if(s.getName() == "Form Responses 1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processed");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);}
  var celldata=s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  var data=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(celldata);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(data, 'Details have been archived to the Processed sheet')
}
```

I ran this test the first time through and it actually generated the output semi-like I want it. I got so excited! 
[image: dialog with data]

But all subsequent tests failed.
Giving only the dialog with  false,,,,,  in the body.

Further I now get this error when I try to walk the function:
*Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,(class)). (line 14, file "TestCode")Dismiss*

I don't understand why the same code works to copy the row of data to the target, but not to define a variable representing the values in those cells for presentation in the dialog.

I know I'm not totally off track.  If I replace this code:

```
var celldata=s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
```

with this code:

```
var celldata="heres some data to review";
```

I get the message pushed out to the dialog.

[image: generic presentation]

....so close...
I similarly tried this code:

```
      var celldata=s.getSheetValues(row, 1, 1, numColumns);
```

But get a similar error when walking the code:
*Cannot find method getSheetValues(number,number,number,(class)). (line 14, file "TestCode")Dismiss*

What am I not understanding about the  getSheetValues  and/or  getRange.getValues  commands?  They sound so logical...

Comment: You already do have a Range variable that is stored as a variable `target`. That contains the copied row. What is it you want to do?

Comment: I've added a couple of lines to give the gist. I want to take that "target" data and push it out to a dialog box.  The end user will put the info into another software and dismiss this dialog.  It requires no interaction other than for them to dismiss the window.
When I run this function on my sheet now, the debugger runs clean but stacklogger says  
"You do not have permission to call showModelessDialog at onEdit(TestCode:16)"

Comment: Have found the issue there. Had to install a trigger.  So excited!  Now am getting the dialog pushed when the row of data moves, the dialog presents and has the title but the body says   undefined  ... so close now.

Comment: @Random Did you work out how to display the body in the Dialog, or are you still looking for help?

Comment: oh indeed I'm still trying things. I just feel this has got to be possible.

Comment: The issue you have--displaying multiple rows of data and not just one--is because `Sheet#getDataRange` creates a `Range` with **all** of the data in the sheet, not just a particular row's data.

Answer (score 0):

For all who may review this code now does what I intended in terms of the question.

```
function onConf(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  var row = r.getRow();
  var column = r.getColumn();
  if(s.getName() == "Form Responses 1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var celldata=s.getSheetValues(row, 2, 1, numColumns);
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processed");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);}
  var data=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(celldata);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(data, 'Details have been archived to the Processed sheet')
}
```

Makes a nice presentation of the data, albeit in need of formatting. 
Also **moves** the line selected to a different sheet.
[image: success]
Can't wait for the 'cuda to show up.